# Android camera preview as background causes restart of Nexus 4

Tags: android, camera, restart

I develop an android app which uses the camera preview as background. I implemented it by following basically http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

However, very randomly, the app causes a restart of my nexus 4, without showing any error logs in the LogCat. I didn't observe this on any other phone I tested the app with. I am pretty sure that it has to do with the camera preview, since it never happened when a disabled this feature.

Does anyone have any ideas what the reason could be? Thanks for any help.

Btw, the LogCat shows sometimes this, but it doesn't cause the crash:

```
 12-12 21:37:01.874: E/mm-libcamera2(175): PROFILE HAL: First preview frame received: 1386880621.879017234
12-12 21:37:01.874: E/QCameraHWI_Preview(175): processPreviewFrameWithDisplay: buffer to be enqueued is not locked
12-12 21:37:02.064: E/qcom_sensors_hal(589): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
```

Comment: I have a Nexus 4, and in a previous project I needed to make a camera activity. I followed this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html (from Vogella) and it was nice and easy. You can also try this one: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/) But without Logcat, it will be difficult to help you with this issue... Good luck.

Comment: I have heard that snapchat also causes random restarts of nexus 4. They say its an android bug. Since it also uses the camera, maybe its the same issue